# Is UIImage(data: Data) asynchronous?

Tags: swift, asynchronous, uiimage, uikit, nsdata

**My issue:** I have reason to believe that initializing a `UIImage` from `Data` gums up my main thread a bit. It isn't terrible, takes a fraction of a second to complete, but it is noticeable as it makes my UI seem a bit glitchy.

**What I'm doing:** I have a `UIPageViewController`. One of the `UIViewController`s presented by said `UIPageViewController` is making use of this `UIImage(data: Data)` initializer in its `viewDidLoad` method:

```swift
class PageViewController: UIPageViewController {

    var pages: [UIViewController] = []

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        loadPages()
    }

    ...

    func loadPages() {

        let vc1 = storyboard!.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "VC1") as! ViewController1
        let vc2 = storyboard!.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "VC2") as! ViewController2
        let vc3 = storyboard!.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "VC3") as! ViewController3
        pages.append(userProfilePreviewVC)
        pages.append(meetVC)
        pages.append(chatLogVC)

        setViewControllers([pages[1]], direction: UIPageViewController.NavigationDirection.forward, animated: false, completion: nil)
    }
}

extension PageViewController: UIPageViewControllerDelegate, UIPageViewControllerDataSource {
    func pageViewController(_ pageViewController: UIPageViewController, viewControllerBefore viewController: UIViewController) -> UIViewController? {

        switch currentIndex {
        case 1:
            return pages[0]
        case 2:
            return pages[1]
        default:
            return nil
        }
    }

    func pageViewController(_ pageViewController: UIPageViewController, viewControllerAfter viewController: UIViewController) -> UIViewController? {
        switch currentIndex {
        case 0:
            return pages[1]
        case 1:
            return pages[2]
        default:
            return nil
        }
    }
}
```

Here is where the issue lies:

```swift
class ViewController1: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet var profilePicButton: UIButton!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        let userPhotos = UserDefaults.standard.array(forKey: "UserPhotos") as? [Data] ?? []
        if userPhotos.count != 0 {
            self.profilePicButton.setImage(UIImage(data: userPhotos.first ?? Data()) ?? UIImage(named: "profile")!, for: .normal)
        } else {
            self.profilePicButton.setImage(UIImage(named: "profile"), for: .normal)
        }
    }
}
```

**My question:** When swiping on my `PageViewController` to the page that is displaying `ViewController1`, the main thread seems to gum up as it takes a fraction of a second to actually load this `ViewController1`. This is in contrast to other view controllers that are instantly ready to go when swiping to them. Similarly, when the user doesn't have any stored profile picture data, a placeholder image that is from my `assets.xcassets` folder takes its place. There is no lag when presenting this image. My question is: **should I use `UIImage(data: Data)` on a background thread and update the button image when the `UIImage` has initialized?**

Comment: You should not use UserDefaults to store image data

Comment: create a folder and save your images straight to disk. You can save their names and location in user defaults if needed

Comment: I apologize, earlier I read your comment as "You should use UserDefaults to store image data". Is there a reason as to why its a bad idea to store image data in `UserDefaults`?

Comment: Could you tell what's the lenght/size of `userPhotos`? I wouldn't use UserDefaults for that. Maybe a "path", but definitely not in UserDefaults, which might be cause for the issue.

Comment: It stores an array or up to 6, non-compressed user images. This can be from their camera roll or camera, so there’s no limit to how large the images could be. When pushed to the backend, the images get compressed, but I’m not compressing images when storing them on the device.

Comment: I ended up going with Leo's suggestion and did this little tutorial https://iswiftdeveloper.wordpress.com/2018/01/30/save-and-get-image-from-document-directory-in-swift/ to convert data stored on the users' `UserDefaults` to storing the data as files in the document directory. This seems to have had a positive impact on performance.